# Debug a ruby project (to become familiar with the code flow)

Tags: ruby, debugging, ide, remote-debugging

Can someone suggest a IDE for Ruby which will make it easier to understand the code flow of the project. I am looking for something similar to intellij remote debugger for JAVA. The debugger should transfer the complete control of the code, so that stepping into and stepping out of the code becomes easier.

Comment: You can use the byebug gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rubymine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) is a very good IDE by JetBrains, so you should be on famillier grounds if you've worked IntelliJ. Among other things, it has a built in debugger with the functionalities you described.

One major caveat though - it's not free, and there's no community edition like there is for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I use [cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/) for Ruby programming and it does everything and more. You get a full Linux environment which includes a terminal, file-tree structure navigation and a code-editor. Best of all it's free to use but there are upgrade options if you need more muscle.

You can even collaborate on it (which you may have to pay for, I'm not sure).